# mutltithreading in C++ does not work with pybind11 to Python

Tags: python, c++, multithreading, pybind11, gil

I am having this difficulty to utilize the multithreading capability of C++ through python's pybind11 plugin system. I am aware of the notorious GIL issue and try to release it but no avail. Following is my C++ code:

```
#include <pybind11/pybind11.h>
#include <pybind11/numpy.h>
#include <pybind11/stl.h>

#include "Calculator.h" // where run_calculator is

namespace py = pybind11;

// wrap c++ function with Numpy array IO
int wrapper(const std::string& input_file, py::array_t<double>& in_results) {
    if (in_results.ndim() != 2)
        throw std::runtime_error("Results should be a 2-D Numpy array");

    auto buf = in_results.request();
    double* ptr = (double*)buf.ptr;

    size_t N = in_results.shape()[0];
    size_t M = in_results.shape()[1];

    std::vector<std::vector<double> > results;

    pybind11::gil_scoped_release release;
    run_calculator(input_file, results);
    pybind11::gil_scoped_acquire acquire;

    size_t pos = 0;
    for (size_t i = 0; i < results.size(); i++) {
        const std::vector<double>& line_data = results[i];
        for (size_t j = 0; j < line_data.size(); j++) {
            ptr[pos] = line_data[j];
            pos++;
        }
    }
}

PYBIND11_MODULE(calculator, m) {
    // optional module docstring
    m.doc() = "pybind11 calculator plugin";

    m.def("run_calculator", &wrapper, "Run the calculator");
}
```

Then on the python side:

```
results= np.zeros((N, M))
start = datetime.datetime.now()
run_calculator(input_file, results)
end = datetime.datetime.now()
elapsed = end - start
print(f'the calculation takes {elapsed.total_seconds()} seconds')
```

Basically the calculator takes in a file path, then return a 2-D array. I get this data passed back to python. In the calculator, I have multi-threading placed.

However, even with this pybind11::gil_scoped_release release, the runtime is not reduced at all. If I run on the C++ side using a main function to call run_calculator, the impact of multithreading is very obvious.

I also tried to declare the module to pybind11 in this way instead of using gil_scoped_release

```
PYBIND11_MODULE(calculator, m) {
    // optional module docstring
    m.doc() = "pybind11 calculator plugin";

    m.def("run_calculator", &wrapper, py::call_guard<py::gil_scoped_release>());
}
```

However the run just crashes.

Anyone can point me to the right direction?

Comment: How can you tell?  That's one single operation.  How can threading possibly help you here?  The run tine of `run_calculator` will not be affected by Python, of course.  The only thing your GIL release does is to allow other Python threads to run at the same time.  What else is running?

Comment: The multi-threading sits in run_calculator. The input_file has hundreds lines of data, and the calculator will launch multi-threads to process these lines in parallel. I can see that multi-threading does reduce the run time in the calculator proportionally if only running C++ part, but with pybind11 and use the python to drive, there is no virtually reduction of run time of the calculator.

Comment: If you use multi-threading inside `run_calculator`, the GIL shouldn't affect this at all. The GIL prevents multiple python threads to run together but it doesn't control what your C++ code does.

Comment: You are right. I do see multi-threading in C++ now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a false alarm. The multithreading is working on the C++ side. GIL has nothing to do with that as long as the threading is not on the python side.